# Using LuaLaTex with BibTex but Citation show up as bold keywords in Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, luatex

I am using LyaLatext for the Aerial font. For some reason, I cannot figure out why my citation is not read correctly.

Here are the packages I set up

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=apa,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,url=false,
      isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Aerial}

\begin{document} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Example citation: reforms in higher education `\citep{siemens2011penetrating}`

It would show up as:

> reforms in higher education **(siemens2011penetrating)**.

My reference is stored in `references.bib` in this format

```
@article{siemens2011penetrating,
  title={Penetrating the fog: Analytics in learning and education.},
  author={Siemens, George and Long, Phil},
  journal={EDUCAUSE review},
  volume={46},
  number={5},
  pages={30},
  year={2011},
  publisher={ERIC}
}
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong? I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're using LuaLaTeX, do *not* load the `inputenc` package.

Comment: Aren't you getting a `! Package biblatex Error: Biber backend is required by style.` error message? Please advise.

Comment: I did not get that error. Instead, I got the following error

Comment: Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }.

<inserted text> 
\par 
l.4 ...ackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}, margin=1in]
                                                  {geometry}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Comment: It also telss me my citation is undefined.

Comment: This is the error message: You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

Comment: And thank you for helping and the welcome @Mico

Comment: Incidentally, is your sans font called `Aerial` or `Arial`?

Comment: It is Arial. So I updated this

Comment: \documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieeetr,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{authblk}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

education \cite{siemens2011penetrating}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Comment: In your initial query, you mentioned that the bib file is called `references.bib`. However, according to the code in the most recent comment, the file's name is actually `reference.bib`. Which one is it?

Comment: Incidentally, when I try to compile the code in the comment, I get the following error message: `Package biblatex Error: Style 'ieeetr' not found`. Please clarify what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've set the `biblatex` option `style=apa`, you *must* use biber, not bibtex, as the back-end. Also, don't load `geometry` twice.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{siemens2011penetrating,
  title  ={Penetrating the fog: Analytics in learning and education.},
  author ={Siemens, George and Long, Phil},
  journal={EDUCAUSE Review},
  volume ={46},
  number ={5},
  pages  ={30},
  year   ={2011},
  publisher={ERIC}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,
            url=false,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial} % Aerial??

\begin{document} 
\citep{siemens2011penetrating}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mico. This works great. I just have another question, does that mean that I have to load my entire bibliography in-between the {filecontents}? I am not familiar with this environment.

Comment: I tried your method with my document. If I don't include the {filecontents} section, but keep everything else you specified above, it still doesn't work. The citation still shows up as bold keywords. It still tells me that my citation is undefined. It seems like it is not reading the references.bib correctly. And also the reference actually does not print at the end of the document, which makes me think that somehow the .bib is not communicating with the .tex file when it is called.

Comment: @VXL963 - Please confirm that you actually run `biber` inbetween LaTeX runs.

Comment: @VXL963 - The `filecontents` environment serves to create external files (here: `references.bib`) "on the fly", which is very useful when creating a self-contained, compilable test document. Of course, if you already have a file called `references.bib`, no need to create another one.

Comment: Yes I am using biber for the backend.

Comment: @VXL963 - I use biber too, and I was able to produce the output recorded in the screenshot shown above. Your description of what you're getting sounds to me like you're either not using biber correctly, that biber can't find the bib file that contains the required entry, or both. Anyway, my psychic abilities are absolutely worthless. Unless you provide more specifics as to what exactly you're doing, chances that I'll figure out successfully what you're doing are nil.